# Rails 5.2 autoload is not working in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a project on Rails 5.2 with the following structure:

- app/
- app/auth
- app/auth/oauth_controller.rb
- app/auth/oauth.rb

**oauth_controller.rb**

```
require_relative "./oauth.rb"

module Auth
  class OauthController < Infra::BaseController
    include ActionController::Cookies

    def start
      oauth = Auth::OAuth.new(session: session)
      ...
    end

    def callback
      oauth = Auth::OAuth.new(session: session)
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

**oauth.rb**

```
module Auth
  class OAuth
    ...
  end
end
```

To have the `Auth::Oauth` working I have to require the `oauth.rb` file, so I think the eager loading or autoload are not working. But, even with the `require()`, when I change the file, I get this error again and I have to restart the server again and again.

> uninitialized constant Auth::OAuth

Here is my **application.rb**

```
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
config.api_only = false
config.eager_load_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app)
config.time_zone = 'Etc/UTC'
config.reload_controllers = !Rails.env.production?
```

The **development.rb** was not changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of naming convention rails expects. Rails is expecting a file name `o_auth.rb` to match `OAuth`. You need to add an infection to support `OAuth` as `oauth.rb`

In `config/initializers/inflections.rb` add

```rb
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym 'OAuth'
end
```

**OR** you need to change your file name to `o_auth.rb`

In both cases you do not need `require_relative "./oauth.rb"`

In addition, if this is a controller it should live in `app/controllers/auth/o_auth` and not directly in `app/`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answer, the folders under `app` are not interpreted as modules and are for organization only. So `app/auth/oauth.rb` Should look like

```
class Oauth
```

Not

```
module Auth
  class Oauth
```

Comment: I don't believe this is a Model so it wouldn't inherit from `ApplicationRecord`

Comment: @theartofbeing - fair enough although fundamentally irrelevant to my point.

Comment: Hi @jvillian, Rails allow us to have a flexible structure. Is not a mandatory thing you have to follow the initial implementation. Thanks for token time to answer!